# Update MySQL data if URL accessed

Tags: mysql, url, if-statement

I would like to know if it's possible to update a MySQL value for a logged in user if he accessed a certain URL. If possible, what's the best way to do so?

Example:

MySQL, 3 columns:

username id count

Each time the user access count.php?ref=12 the "count" value should be changed (if it was 10) to 9.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033537/php-mysql-how-to-safely-increment-mysql-integer-field

Comment: Include the code updating mysql in the header (html <head> section) of your page.

Answer (score 0):

I have the found the following solution and seems to be working:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin where username='$user_check' ") 
          or die(mysql_error()); 
          while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
          $status = $_GET['urlvalue'];
          if($status == "0")
          {
          $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE admin SET count = (count - 1) where username='$user_check'");
          }
```