# I am having some issue to update my database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a counter in php to see how many people land on the page.

```
<?php

                    $update = "UPDATE `users` SET `views`='$views[$index]' WHERE `email`='$email[$index]'";
                    $views[$index] = $views[$index] + 1;
                    if (mysql_query($update)){
                    echo $views[$index];}

                ?>
```

Comment: So... what's the problem? Are you getting an error? Is something unexpected happening?

Comment: Switch the first two lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell what exactly the problem is, but I'm assuming that the number does not increment. I believe that your SQL is incorrect.

Have you tried something similar to what is specified in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033537/php-mysql-how-to-safely-increment-mysql-integer-field)?

Try some SQL like this:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `views` = `views` + 1 WHERE `email`=".$email[$index]."`";
```

Although, please notice that both my code and your code is vulnerable to a potential SQL injection attack (depending on where you get the $email variable, it may be alright in your case). Try this out and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are reading from the database earlier in your code.

As you had it $views[$index'] would not have been correctly interpreted so I have put it into a local scalar $vcnt

if there is still a problem the extra debug line should show what it is

```
 <?php
 $views[$index]++;
 $vcnt=$views[$index];
 $emailadr=$email[$index];
 $update = "UPDATE `users` SET `views`='$vcnt' WHERE `email`='$emailadr'";
 if (mysql_query($update)){ echo "ok: $vcnt";}
 else                     { echo "error: $vcnt : $update";}
 ?>
```