# How to get max from sql in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, max

So I'm buidlign a website currently and there is a form connected to a database.

You can put some information in the form and it will send you an email and will put the information into the database.

So... I wanted it also ad a number into the database and auto count the number. This lead me thinking.... If I use max and just do +1 and insert that, Jobs done right!!.... Well no....

The code isn't working for me and I have no idea where to start...

This is al I made and when I do this I only get 1 as an answer.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT MAX(Nummer) FROM Leerling" ;
$sql3 = $sql2 + 1;

echo $sql3;
```

The insert statement is

`"INSERT INTO Leerling(Nummer, Naam, Klas, Email, Bericht) VALUES ('" . $sql3 . "', '" .$naam. "', '" .$klas. "' , '" .$email. "', '" .$bericht. "');" ;`

Which only inserts 0 into the database on the place where it says $sql2. I'm totaly clueless so any help is much needed help.

(Don't mind my English if it's not correct >.< I'm Dutch)

Comment: Your `$sql2` var is just a string. You need to actually connect to a database via PDO/mysqli  (but you also specified sql-server??) and execute the query.

Comment: But really rather than do any of this, you should set up `Nummer` to be an auto-increment, then let the database do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP-MySQL-How to safely increment MySQL integer field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033537/php-mysql-how-to-safely-increment-mysql-integer-field)

Comment: And use a prepared statement for your insert statement, which is currently vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use MySQL [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Your column Nummer will increase its value every time you insert a new row and no need for calculate the MAX value to increase Nummer for the new row

Comment: You are my hero. Thank you so much I've been wrestling with this one for over a hour. I didn't know it could be so easy.